# Set common build parameters for every branch in Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a Jenkins multibranch item and several branches where the Jenkins pipeline file is.
I also have several common parameters which are actual for every of those branches (like test Groups to run, selenium properties etc.)

How can I define the set of those parameters in Jenkins interface so they will appear for each run of branch so that each new branch automatically becomes as "Parameterized build"? I can see this flag in the configuration of particular branch build (can't save it, though):

[image]

But not in the multibranch item's configuration.

**Jenkins 2.89.3**

Comment: As I know it's not possible to define default parameters for new branches/jobs. So you would have to insert them manually for each new branch or write in Jenkinsfile if you don't change them often

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just needed to define them in properties step in the pipeline...

```
 properties([
                parameters([
                        string(name: 'one', defaultValue: ''),
                        string(name: 'second', defaultValue: ''),
                        string(name: 'third', defaultValue: ''),
                ])
        ])
```

It's a magic! :)

Answer (score 2):

For the latests versions of Jenkins you might get this error: *The ‘properties’ section has been renamed as of version 0.8.* You can use the **parameters** directive:

Doc: [Pipeline Syntax: Parameters](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters)

Here is an example:

```
pipeline {
  parameters {
    string(name: 'MY_PARAM', defaultValue: '', description: 'My parameter')
  }

  agent {
    label 'docker-slave'
  }

  environment {
    DURATION=240
  }

  stages {

    stage('First Stage') {
      when {
        beforeAgent true
      }
      steps {
        sh  "echo ${params.MY_PARAM}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!